# How does one add source to a .class file on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, .class-file

I am trying to add a date.class file to my eclipse project, but it returns **Source Not Found**. How do I create/ add a source file from a class file?

Comment: A class file is not a source file.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. How are you adding a .class file to you project?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a library that you are using to your java project you can attach source by expanding the project node in package explorer view -> Referenced Libraries -> Locate your jar -> Right click, properties -> Java Source attachment.